# Not allocating extra partition in dual boot laptop Windows10/Ubuntu18.04?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

[image: partitions]

Above are my drive partitions, the last one **(200.63 GB)** is for **ubuntu 18.04**. I want to create an extra partition from **DATA (D:) (490 GB)**. When I shrink volume from **DATA (D:) (490 GB)** and try to allocate space it will display below error message

[image: error message]

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what can I do?

The error message is self-explanatory:

> (...) the disk already contains the maximum number of partitions

which is 4 (four) **primary** partitions for "msdos" (MBR) partitioning style/type. GPT drives have no such limitation.

The way around this limitation - used by many Linux distros installers - is to create/have one primary partition containing two or more logical partitions inside. This however cannot be done without data loss - not a problem if you have backups - because the current partition must be removed before creating a new one containing the required logical partitions. And third-party tools are required. GParted in a live Linux session can be used.

Comment: Also, you can't boot (at least not directly with firmware) from a logical partition. Really the best bet is to convert the disk to GPT, provided your firmware supports booting from GPT. As of the Windows 10 "creator's update" Windows comes with a tool that can do this to your existing system disk, but it would likely lose the Ubuntu OS that you have in that 200 GB, because it doesn't know anything about it. You'd have to back that stuff up somewhere and then put it back after the conversion.